# Nonlinear bounded optimization in R

Tags: r, constraints, bounds, nonlinear-optimization

I am trying to run a nonlinear optimization with bounded constraints in R.
I have got to know `NlcOptim` & `roptim` can be used to optimize a nonlinear objective function, and I have gone through examples [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NlcOptim/NlcOptim.pdf] like one (ex1) as I have mentioned below;

```
require(NlcOptim)
require(MASS)
objfun=function(x){
  return(exp(x[1]*x[2]*x[3]*x[4]*x[5]))
}
#constraint function
confun=function(x){
  f=NULL
  f=rbind(f,x[1]^2+x[2]^2+x[3]^2+x[4]^2+x[5]^2-10)
  f=rbind(f,x[2]*x[3]-5*x[4]*x[5])
  f=rbind(f,x[1]^3+x[2]^3+1)
  #return(list(ceq=f,c=NULL))
  return(list(ceq=f,c=NULL))
}
x0=c(-2,2,2,-1,-1)
solnl(x0,objfun=objfun,confun=confun)
```

Understanding:
x used in both objfun & confun, is a vector containing x(i), i=1(1)5
x0 is the starting values (In this case, I am bit confused as we are not defining here the bounds of x1,..,x5, rather only the initial values)

I have tried to replicate this example for my actual problem, the objective function I framed is as below;

```
Maximize P= (x*y*z)-(cost1 + cost2 + cost3 + cost4 + cost5 + cost6) 
where
cost1 = 5000
cost2 = (0.23*cost1) + (0.67*x*y) 
cost3 = 0.2* cost1+ (0.138*x*y)
cost4 = 0.62*cost1
cost5 = 0.12* cost1
cost6 = 0.354*x
Boundaries for the variables are as follow;
200<=x=>350
17<=y=>60
964<=z=>3000
```

Having this problem in hand, I tried to formulate this as code;

```
x <- runif(2037,200,350)
y <- runif(2037,17,60)
z <- seq(964,3000,1)  # z is having highest length of 2037. But not sure if this the way to define bounds!!
data_comb <- cbind(x,y,z)
mat <- as.matrix(data_comb)

cost1 <- 5000
cost2 <- (0.23*cost1) + (0.67* mat[,1])* (mat[,2]) 
cost3 <- 0.2* cost1+ (0.138* mat[,1])* (mat[,2])
cost4 <- rep(0.62*cost1, dim(mat)[1])
cost5 <- rep(0.12* cost1, dim(mat)[1])
cost6 <- 0.354* mat[,1]
#Objective function
objfun <- function(mat){
  return((mat[,1]*mat[,2]*mat[,3]) - (cost1 + cost2 + cost3 + cost4 + cost5 + cost6))
}
#Constraints
confun=function(mat){
  f=NULL
  f=rbind(f,(0.23*cos1) + (0.67*mat[,1])* (mat[,2]))
  f=rbind(f,(0.2*cost1) + (0.138*mat[,1])*(mat[,2]))
  f=rbind(f,0.354*mat[,1])
  return(list(ceq=f,c=NULL))
}
x0 <- c(200,17,964)
solnl(x0,objfun=objfun,confun=confun)
```

This is giving me an error

```
Error in mat[, 2] : subscript out of bounds
```

I am having a feel somehow I am not replicating the example properly for my problem, but at the same time not able to understand what I am missing. I don’t know if I have defined the bounds properly or how to include multivariate bounds in the function. Please help me in solving this optimization problem.

TIA

Comment: In the example, the functions are using vectors inside them. And `x0` is also a vector. But in your setting, you use matrix named mat inside the functions but you still give a vector to the functions which is `x0` again. So it takes it as `x0[,2]` and can not find a dimension since it is a vector! That is why you get  **subscript out of bounds** warning. I think you should call  `solnl(mat,objfun=objfun,confun=confun)`  instead. Or some other matrices which have at least three columns.

Comment: getting same error if I replace x0 with mat. And if I need to use mat, what's the role of x0? @maydin

Comment: I meant, In the example codes, there is no vector defined x. But it works perfectly. So it means, it takes x0 (initial values) and pass it inside the functions. You are replicating it but you use a matrix instead while you still using a vector.  The question is, how your inital values can be passed inside the matrices if they are inside a vector?

Comment: Can you please explain and solve the problem with some code?

Comment: I am not confident the way I have defined the bounds too.. so it will be helpful if can please post some code to resolve it

Comment: Sorry. I haven't used this library before. I just warned you about the differences I saw btw the example and your codes.

Comment: On my machine, `solnl(mat,objfun=objfun,confun=confun)` works perfectly. There is a typo in your `confun`, it says `cos1` instead of `cost1`. About the bounds: I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Unfortunately, for my case it is giving

solnl(mat,objfun=objfun,confun=confun)
Error in Q[, (iact + 1):numVar] : subscript out of bounds
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no nonlinear constraints, only box constraints, therefore no reason to apply a specialized package or function.

```
obj <- function(v) {
    x <- v[1]; y <- v[2]; z <- v[3]
    cost1 <- 5000
    cost2 <- (0.23*cost1) + (0.67*x*y) 
    cost3 <- 0.2* cost1+ (0.138*x*y)
    cost4 <- 0.62*cost1
    cost5 <- 0.12* cost1
    cost6 <- 0.354*x
    w <- (x*y*z) - (cost1 + cost2 + cost3 + cost4 + cost5 + cost6)
    return(-w)
}

o <- optim(c(200,17,964), obj, method = "L-BFGS-B",
           lower = c(200,17,964), upper = c(350,60,3000))

o$par; -o$value
## [1]  350   60 3000
## [1] 62972058
```

For using `NlcOptim:solnl()` you can define the box constraints with the `lb` and `ub` option arguments, just the same as above.

```
NlcOptim::solnl(c(200,17,964), obj,
                lb = c(200,17,964), ub = c(350,60,3000))
```

with the same result, showing that your function does not have a real, inner maximum. Or you can integrate the bounds into the constraint function